# What does it mean for two $2 \times 2$ matrices to be orthogonal to each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

This is just a quick question about definitions.  What exactly does it mean for two matrices to be orthogonal to each other?  Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind.  I misread the question.  Maybe someone could delete this post

Comment: Can you give the context? My guess is that the rows (or columns) of one matrix will be orthogonal with respect to the rows (or columns) of the other. In other words, they form a pair of dual bases w.r.t. the scalar product.

Comment: I misread it.  It wanted me to show they are orthogonal and I read it as orthogonal to each other.

Comment: I don't see the need for deletion.  It'll be helpful for the next person who encounters this same situation.

Answer (score 6):

This is an inner product on the space of all $2\times 2$ matrices:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1\\c_1&d_1\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}a_2&b_2\\c_2&d_2\end{pmatrix}=a_1a_2+2b_1b_2+c_1c_2+2d_1d_2.$$

As soon as we have an inner product, we have that the matrices are orthogonal if their inner product is zero.

Of course, there may be other inner products and the definition of orthogonality will change accordingly.

Comment: +1 Good for you! (My earlier comment wasn't a criticism, just encouragement for you to post a fine answer!)

Comment: Just curious: why not use the standard Frobenius inner product as an example?

Answer (score 0):

A matrix can BE orthogonal ([as described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)) but I have never heard of matrices being **orthogonal to each other.**

Comment: This is an inner product on the space of all $2\times 2$ matrices:

$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix} a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2\end{pmatrix}=a_1a_2+2b_1b_2+c_1c_2+2d_1d_2$

Comment: @Shahab: Are you stating that some property of the inner product on the space of 2x2 matrices (such as perhaps equalling 0) makes matrices orthogonal to each other? That would be a definition consistent with other uses of the term orthogonal.

Comment: Yes of course. As soon as we have an inner product, we have that the matrices are orthogonal if their inner product is zero.

Comment: @Shahab why don't you post your comments as an answer?

Comment: @amWhy: I thought the question was going to be deleted and wanted to respond to Pieter before that happened. A comment seemed the quickest way to notify him. I have now posted it as an answer.